# react is not rendering with node.js

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a web app with node.js.
I am using ejs, but I am trying to use react only for certain pages (/react).
When I do an npm start in the my-app directory, I see (http://localhost:3000/react) successfully.

On the other hand, when I start in the root directory and view (http://localhost:3001/react/), the index.html of react is displayed but not rendered.

Any advice would be appreciated.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq2kp.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhngA.png)

How do I get Hello to appear on the (http://localhost:3001/react/) page?